# Setting a dynamic margin

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this issue with setting a margin that dynamical decreases and increases to a minimum of 8px and maximum of 40px.

The margin is being set between 11 different blocks which are inside a container. The container can be a minimum width of 960px or a maximum of 1280px and always has a fixed height.

How can I make it so that the space (margin-left) in between the boxes always stretches to fill the container correctly?

Below is an image of what I am aiming for at 960px width

[image: 960px width container]

Now an an image of it at it's full width of 1280px

[image: 1280px width container]

As you can see from the images all im trying to do is separate the boxes as the resolution is changed.

I currently have something like this using jQuery

```
$(window).bind('resize', function(){ 
    var barWidth = $(".topBar").width(); 
    $(".barModules li").css('margin-left', my dynamic value here));
});
```

I'm stuck on how I should be calculating this and if that's even the right way to go about it :/

An example of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/m4rGp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't do that with javascript. Its a lot of work

You could make a table with cells that are set to the width you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/HZKpM/

You can even add a `minwidth` in various places.

Comment: Thanks, It get the job done, but I'm not sure about the use of tables :/ I thought it was an 'avoid in using for layout' approach for them in web design... unless using a table in this situation win's against the amount of JavaScript work/complexity needed, what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

If...

```
n = number of LI elements in .barModules
```

then...

```
dynamic margin = (barWidth - n * (width of one LI)) / (n - 1)
```

So your code would look like:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function(){ 
    var n = $(".barModules li").length;
    var barWidth = $(".topBar").width();
    var liWidth = $(".barModules li:first").width; // if set through CSS, read the "style" attribute instead...
    var dynMargin =  (barWidth - n * liWidth) / (n - 1)

    $(".barModules li").css('margin-right', dynMargin + "px"));  // "margin-right" instead of "margin-left"
    $(".barModules li:last").css('margin-right', '0px');  // don't need margin on last element.
});

// if .length isn't returning the a value for "n", there are other ways to count the sub-elements, check the "children()" method at jquery.com
```

Comment: Thank you for this, It works, but on my site another percentage setting I'm using causes issues and therefore, in my situation makes it unreliable. I'm providing a link to it working in jsFiddle for future reference - http://jsfiddle.net/m4rGp/1/ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using CSS.  Just create an outer box around each box.

```
<div class="outer"><div class="inner">text</div></div>
```

Here is a jsfidle http://jsfiddle.net/HZKpM/3/

Comment: Very interesting, however I need my boxes to be 80px in width, and for them to start and end against the very edges of the container (E.G. In your jsFiddle I need there to be no orange at the start or end) Do you know if this would be possible in CSS? Many thanks!

Comment: Do you know CSS?  B/c the widths and colors are written directly in there, nothing fancy.  Just change it to `width:80px` and delete the background style.  Update: http://jsfiddle.net/HZKpM/5/

Comment: Ahh lol sorry that comment was not very clear! I was trying to say that within my container, both end boxes must be against the edges of the container. For example, http://jsfiddle.net/HZKpM/7/ You can see orange at the end of the container) Is there a way to get the very right and very left boxes up against the edges of the container whilst still having the spaces in between the rest.